# Using easyTable with FPDI in PHP

Tags: php, pdf-generation, fpdf, fpdi

I'm trying to generate PDF using FPDF - easyTable and FPDI (beacuse I need to use template of pdf file) and it's not working. I get an error:

> **Fatal error:** Class 'setasign\Fpdi\FpdfTpl' not found in 
>       **C:\xampp\htdocs\TestFPDI\fpdi\src\Fpdi.php** on line **24**

I make every step like written here: [fpdf-easytable/using-easytable-with](https://github.com/fpdf-easytable/fpdf-easytable#using-with-fpdi), but it's still not working.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php 

  include 'fpdf.php'; 
  include 'fpdi.php'; 
  include 'exfpdf.php'; 
  include 'easyTable.php'; 

  $pdf = new exFPDF(); 

  $pdf->AddPage('L'); 
  $pdf->AddFont('arial_ce','','arial_ce.php');
  $pdf->AddFont('arial_ce','I','arial_ce_i.php');
  $pdf->AddFont('arial_ce','B','arial_ce_b.php');
  $pdf->AddFont('arial_ce','BI','arial_ce_bi.php');
  $pdf->SetFont('arial_ce', '', 9);

  $pdf->setSourceFile("example-2.pdf"); 
  $tplIdx = $pdf->importPage(1); 
  $pdf->useImportedPage($tplIdx);

  $table1=new easyTable($pdf, 2); 
  $table1->easyCell('Sales Invoice', 'font-size:30; font-style:B; font-color:#00bfff;'); 
  $table1->easyCell('', 'img:fpdf.png, w80; align:R;'); 
  $table1->printRow(); 

  $pdf->Output(); 

?>
```

Comment: Please show the complete PHP code as I don't see the starting PHP tag, i.e., `<?php...`.

Comment: My mistake. Now it's all added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found resolution for my problem so I post it here:

After add **use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi** in exFPDF file everything is working great.

```
use \setasign\Fpdi\Fpdi;
class exFPDF extends FPDI {

}
```

Thanks for trying!